# Office Scriprt Error Pivot Filter properties of undefined

Tags: pivot, office-scripts

I'm a newbie concering Office Script, maybe you could help me out.

I'm trying to apply Filters to a Pivot, but I'm getting the error: cannont read propertis of undefined (reading 'get fields')

I found out that i have forgotten to define something, but I don't know how to this in the code, here's my try:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

//Pivot definieren
  let BasisFreiBlatt = workbook.getWorksheet("Basis FreiER");
  const PivotFreiER = BasisFreiBlatt.getPivotTable("PivotFreiER");

  //Filter Pivot
//Feld Frei ER auf nein
  const freierField = PivotFreiER.getFilterHierarchy("frei ER");
   getFields()[0];
  freierField.applyFilter({
    manualFilter: {
    selectedItems: ["nein"] /* The included items. */
    }
  });

  //Feld arch auf nein
  const archField = PivotFreiER.getFilterHierarchy("arch").getFields()[0];
  archField.applyFilter({
    manualFilter: {
      selectedItems: ["nein"] /* The included items. */
    }
  });

  //Feld Ladetermin auf x
  const ladeterminField = PivotFreiER.getFilterHierarchy("Ladetermin").getFields()[0];
  ladeterminField.applyFilter({
    manualFilter: {
      selectedItems: ["x"] /* The included items. */
    }
  });

}
```

google search
chat gpt
foren

Answer (score 0):

Pls try.

```js
//Filter Pivot
//Feld Frei ER auf nein
  const freierField = PivotFreiER.getFilterHierarchy("frei ER").getFields()[0];
  freierField.applyFilter({
    manualFilter: {
    selectedItems: ["nein"] /* The included items. */
    }
  });
```